# Change Redshift Materialized View Owner

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a materialized view that needs refreshed as part of my ETL pipeline. The ETL pipeline is ran by an ETL user.

I am getting the following error when trying to refresh:

> ERROR: Only owner of MV dbo.mat_view can invoke REFRESH.

I have searched the documentation and cannot find anything on changing the owner of the materialized view. I have also tried the following:

```
GRANT ALL 
ON dbo.mat_view 
TO dev_etl_user;
```

as well as this (which I use on tables)

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW dbo.mat_view 
OWNER TO dev_etl_user;
```

But neither work when running

```
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION dev_etl_user;
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW dbo.mat_view;
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I do the `ALTER TABLE` command and it appears to change the user, but I still get the `Only owner of MV` error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Redshift.

The sql query that worked for me was this:

```
ALTER table <your_schema>.<your_mv> OWNER TO <new_owner>;
```

You can check the changes with the following query:

```
select name, owner_user_name from STV_MV_INFO where schema = <your_schema>;
```